# Difference between 2 collections? (elements in collection1, but not in collection2)

Tags: java, list, collections, set, guava

In Java (maybe using Guava?), is there some method provided to get the difference of two `Collection`s, e.g. a `List` and a `Set` *without* modifying one of these `Collection`s (else there would be `collection1.removeAll(collection2)`?

In Guava there is `Sets.difference(set1,set2)`, but it only works for `Set`s, not for arbitrary collections.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Why not just simply copy `collection1` elements to `testCollection` and do `testCollection.removeAll(collection2)`?

Comment: Obviously this is one solution, but I am wondering if there is already some method for my use case provided, without copying collection1 first?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf any possible solution will either have to perform a copy or modify the input. There's no other way

Comment: I correct to without me actively copying it, so shorter in code, like some are already provided as answers :-)

Answer (score 13):

You can filter the first `Collection` using built-in `Predicate`s:

```
Collections2.filter(c1, Predicates.not(Predicates.in(c2))
```

It works with any kind of `Collection`s, but obviously it's better if `c2` is a `Set`.

Answer (score 4):

ApacheCommons CollectionUtils has a method named [disjuction](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) that

> Returns a Collection containing the exclusive disjunction (symmetric difference) of the given Iterables

Comment: I think [substract](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#subtract(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) is the method appropriate here.